# What does "the chicken" refer to?

Tags: plot-explanation, the-departed

On a monitor in *The Departed* (2006), Sullivan identifies everyone present with Irish Mob boss
Frank near the building that they have under AV surveillance nearby.
Frank checks his phone and sees a message from Sullivan that reads "No phones."

> Sullivan: Time is 10:46.

Frank and his gang enters the building:

> Frank: All right, turn off your cell phones. Fitzy's got **the chicken**.
> Check your weapons.

What does "the chicken" refer to?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This would appear to be their own internal slang for '*the suitcase containing the stolen goods*', noting that Fitzy is seen holding the suitcase a few seconds earlier as they enter the building.

[image]

As to why they refer to it as 'the chicken', they're being very cautious and suspect that they're under surveillance. If they are indeed being observed or overheard then saying "*the contraband*" or "*the illegal stolen chips*" would place them all in jeopardy, whereas they could argue that they [literally thought](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plausible_deniability) that they were transporting some meat products.

---

It would probably be too much to assume that this is a pun (e.g. "[chicken & chips](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chicken_and_chips)") as that tends to be more of a British idiom